# Accessing member variable of AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to wrap my head around singletons and I understand that the App Delegate is essentially a singleton object. I'm trying have some member variables in App Delegate that I can access from any other class. I did this in the App Delegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow            *window;
    RootViewController  *viewController;
    int screenwidth;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) int screenwidth;
```

Then in the .m I did this:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
  ...
   screenwidth=400; //arbitrary test number
```

Now I have another class in the project, and it does this in the .h:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

In the .m I have this somewhere:

```
  test=(AppDelegate*)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] screenwidth];
```

However, it claims that "screenwidth" is an instance method that is not found. I also tried this:

```
test=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].screenwidth;
```

This uses the dot syntax since `screenwidth` was synthesized, but it claims that `property screenwidth not found`

I'm sure these are basic issues that can be corrected simply. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider trying:

```
test=[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] screenwidth];
```

I think your two tries are trying to cast the `.screenwidth` result to an `AppDelegate*`.

Comment: You totally intended that pun.  Don't lie.

Comment: It's true that the cast was incorrect, but that's not the cause of the specified error. (Or, if it is, the compiler needs a good kick in the head.)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're either providing your own `-screenwidth` accessor or using the `@synthesize` directive to get the compiler to provide one:

```
@synthesize screenwidth
```

The `@property` directive is just a promise that accessors for the `screenwidth` property will be provided. You still have to provide them as described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid casting to your AppDelegate class every time, I recommend the following:

In `MyAppDelegate.h`:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>

+ (MyAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;

@property (nonatomic) int screenwidth;

/* ... */

@end
```

In `MyAppDelegate.m`:

```
@implementation LcAppDelegate

+ (MyAppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

/* ... */

@end
```

Of course, you still need to `#import "MyAppDelegate.h"` in the files where you want to access it:

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

/* ... */

NSLog(@"the apps screen width: %d", [MyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].screenwidth);
```

BTW, note that you should not use `int`'s and the like in Objective-C code. Instead, use `NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`, `CGFloat` and so on.